# trying to recreate a bug; need to be asked for password when doing a git fetch

Tags: git, debugging, fetch, passwords

I know there are lots of posts about how NOT to be asked for a password when you do a git fetch, but I am trying to recreate a bug that happens when you do get asked for a password when doing a git fetch.  I've tried a few different things with oyxkeychain etc. and somehow I just can't recreate a scenario where I get asked for a password when doing a git fetch with bitbucket and with github, doesn't matter which one. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a password caching mechanism? Or using ssh (with certificates) as transport?

Comment: I'm not using SSH

Answer (score 0):

Use the following shell commands:

```bash
git init
git remote add origin 'https://nobody@github.com/doot/repo.git'
git fetch origin
```

It should then ask you for a password.

### Explanation

If your remote URL starts with HTTPS, git uses your netrc file (`~/.netrc`) for login credentials. For example, this entry will allow me to push to codeberg.org over HTTPS:

```
machine codeberg.org
 login h3xx
 password 0000000000aaaaaa0000000000aaaaaa12345678
```

If the username/password combo is rejected, it'll ask for both username and password.

If you specify the username in the remote URL, e.g. `https://user@codeberg.org/my-repo.git`, it'll only ask for the password.

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately that doesn't seem to do it for me.  When I go to open a PR and git fetch, I need it to ask me for a password and it still doesn't.

Comment: @ReneePetit "When I go to open a PR and git fetch, I need it to ask me for a password" - I'm confused, those two actions are completely unrelated. Are you saying the website needs to ask you for a password, or the terminal needs to ask you for a password?

Comment: Sorry to be confusing!  Never mind the PR part; that's just related to my specific project.  I just mean git fetch / git fetch all, I need it to ask me for a password.  I finally got it to do that, but it still didn't trigger my bug... so I'm back to the drawing board.  Thanks for your help!